# excel onchange with combobox

Tags: excel, combobox, onchange

I have a spreadsheet where one field is a combobox with 5 answers.
I need to track the date of any changes to this combobox in a hidden field/column for later anaysis.
Any ideas on how to apply the onchange command?

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ideas but not sure exactly what you're after! What point are you at? What have you tried?

You'd probably want to go to the code window and write some VBA under the Change event for the combo box.

```
Private Sub cboMyComboBoxName_Change()
   Sheets("Worksheet").Range("A5").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

Would be a good start, although you'd probably want to apply additional logic to output dates in a meaningful way that you can later process.